# How to make an if-else statement without error?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have to make an if statement but it says error. I have a variable called `cancercode`. I want the codes that are NOT equal to the codes stated below to state as "other" in dataframe.

```
df6 <- df4x%>%
mutate(sygdomsgruppex = ifelse(cancercode != "DC911", "DC833", "DC830", 
                             "DC910", "DC921", "DC831", "DC859","DC919", "DC911B",
                             "Other", cancercode))
```

This code gives me this error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: unused arguments ("DC910", "DC921", "DC831", "DC859","DC919", "DC911B", "other", cancerKode).

Answer (score 1):

```
other_vector <- c("DC911", "DC833", "DC830", "DC910", "DC921", "DC831", "DC859","DC919", "DC911B")
df4x%>%
  mutate(sygdomsgruppex = ifelse(cancercode %in% other_vector, "Other", cancercode))
```